# Query django postgres nested jsonfield

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class Entity(Model):
    lang = CharField()
    data = JSONField()
```

How can I query this model to find all objects that contain a given value. 
JSON can be nested.

For example, if `data` is

```
[
{
   'name': 'Alfred',
   'children': [{'name': 'Bob', 'children':['name': 'Melanie']}] 
},
{
   'name': 'Harry',
   'children': [{'name': 'Helen'}] 
}
]
```

Then I want to return it if I search for `Melanie`. There can be any level of nesting.

From the documentation `Entity.objects.filter(data__values__contains=['Melanie'])` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this, Using a while loop to flatly check each level, until no children are found:

```
children = 'data__children'
results = {}
while children:
    try:
        # does the children array have anything on this iteration?
        # data__children__exists
        # data__children__data__children__exists
        # and so on

        items = Entity.objects.filter(**{f"{children}__exists": True})
        if not len(items):
             children = None

        # filter for "data__children__name__icontains"
        # "data__children__children__name__icontains"
        # and so on for each loop

        f = {"{children}__name__icontains": "melanie"}

        # add the filtered names
        results.update({children: Entity.objects.filter(*f)})

        children += '__data__children'
        # or possibly "__children" here ???
        # just how arbitrary are the recursion keys?
    except:
        children = None
print(results)
```

Comment: What if I have arbitrary structure of json?

Comment: Don't know ahead on what level children could be.

Comment: @AndrewFount I see, updated. Does this make sense for you?

Comment: What if I have {'name': 'Alfred', 'data': [[{'name': 'John', 'children': ['name': 'Melanie']}]]} ?

Comment: @AndrewFount so what exactly does the recursed keys look like? something like `obj.data.children.data.children.data.children.data.children.data.children...`?

Comment: The structure is absolutely arbitrary. Is there any way to find the given value or it will take too much time?

Comment: `[x for x in Entity.objects.all() if 'Melanie' in str(x.data.__dict__)]` ... possibly if the json is indeed arbitrary. @AndrewFount good luck

Comment: Thank you. But this is very slow.